# UI can't be accessed

Tags: views

I noticed 3 issues with my site and I feel they are all related:

1. The context link is absent from admin/structures. When i type www.example.com/admin/structure/context, it redirects back to www.example.com/admin/structure.
2. Also Views is missing from the structure menu

Both the Context and Views U.I modules are enabled.

3. When I go to the /admin/reports/dblog page, the message and operations column are blank as in the image below.

[image: Screenshot from www.example.com/admin/reports/dblog]

The UI issues started after i re-enabled the modules. I previously disabled them on my site but now need to make some edits.

I have tried clearing cache a couple of times. I have also manually emptied the cache menu table in the Database.

I am logged in as User 1.

I would be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

Comment: I would check for MySQL issues/log messages, hard drive space issues, web server errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As per your "*after I re-enabled the modules*": try to (temporary) increase your PHP memory limit (eg with 25%) to see if you get different results ... Doing so *might* get to work it as normal again.

That's one of the typial things I (temporary) do if such kind of issues come up (typically after enable of 1 or more extra modules due to which the current memory limit is not sufficient anymore).